# ip static route, make changes permanent/persistent upon reboot

Tags: linux, routes

On CentOS 5 I manually added a static route to make all packets to one specific IP address use the second network interface:

```
ip route add 123.456.7.89/32 via 192.168.10.101 dev eth1
```

Is there a way to make this change be persistent on reboot without adding it to the startup script `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Add the line:

```
123.456.7.89/32 via 192.168.10.101 dev eth1
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` as shown [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html).

Comment: thanks, much appreciated. I did a lot of googling but it seems I skip this one, way too many tabs opened :)

Answer (score 4):

While [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/108291/197039) works, the current preferred format for `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX` is:

```
GATEWAY0=10.156.196.1
NETMASK0=255.255.254.0
ADDRESS0=10.156.248.0
GATEWAY1=10.156.196.1
NETMASK1=255.255.254.0
ADDRESS1=10.156.244.0
```

Be sure to increment the value of the numeral when you add a route.

Unfortunately, the new preferred format of `GATEWAYX:/ADDRESSx:/NETMASKx:/` makes it harder to programmatically add static routes via the older format of `192.168.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.1`. It can be worked around, but adds unnecessary complications to scripting routes.